# In my MVC .NET Core 3.1 project, how can I prevent the anchor tag helper from appending Area to the querystring?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm migrating an old MVC web application from Visual Studio to Visual Studio Code, and am using .NET Core 3.1.301. The application uses areas. I'm attempting to create a link from this site's home page to the index page of a target area.

Using the anchor tag helper, my Razor resembles this:

```
<a asp-area="TargetArea" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">link</a>
```

My expectation is that the above will produce this markup in the rendered HTML:

```
<a href="/TargetArea">link</a>
```

Instead, this gets rendered:

```
<a href="/TargetArea?area=TargetArea">link</a>
```

In Startup.cs I have defined TargetArea:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "TargetArea",
    pattern: "TargetArea/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In the HomeController within my area, I've decorated the controller with an Area attribute, like so:

```
[Area("TargetArea")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So what am I missing here?  I'd like to make that query-string go away. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route template like below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "TargetArea",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

The second way:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "TargetArea",
        pattern:"TargetArea/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { area = "TargetArea" }, 
        constraints: new { area = "TargetArea" }) ;
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Another way:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "MyTargetArea",
        areaName: "TargetArea",
        pattern: "TargetArea/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#areas

Comment: Thanks, @Rena, I will give this a shot tonight.

Comment: Rena, thank you. The first pattern produced <a href="/?area=TargetArea">link</>. But the second and third patterns worked as desired. Thanks so much!